# Use .NET in VB6 or classical ASP

Tags: .net, com, vb6, asp-classic, wrapper

**Duplicate of** [Calling .NET methods from VB6 via COM visible DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233284/calling-net-methods-from-vb6-via-com-visible-dll)

Which ways exist to use/call .NET classes/functions/libraries (.net 3.x) in VB6 or classical ASP ?
Has anybody experiences with that ? How much effort is necessary to wrap .NET to COM ?
Are there tools which help ?

Comment: That question is not a duplicate - it's a very specific question about a problem with a particular routine. This question is much more general.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling .NET methods from VB6 via COM visible DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233284/calling-net-methods-from-vb6-via-com-visible-dll)

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy actually and I have created .NET components called from both VB6 COM dlls and Classic ASP. You essentially need to create a COM callable wrapper thats exposes the .NET component to a COM client. This article will get you started

[**Calling a .NET component from a COM component**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973802.aspx)

A couple of pointers

- Any COM callable types will need a public parameterless constructor
- Mark public any methods, properties or events that you want to expose to COM.
- It's a good idea to [**explicitly implement an interface**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fcadw4a.aspx) as opposed to relying on one to be generated from your class for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. .Net has functionality for generating a COM wrapper.

This is covered in this question: [Calling .NET methods from VB6 via COM visible DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233284/calling-net-methods-from-vb6-via-com-visible-dll)

- Call .net classes from VB6 is done using a COM wrapper. This is the same in 2.0 as in 3.5. However, it is supposed to be much improved in 4.0.
- The effort is the same as working with COM in general
- In visual studio there is a setting "COM visible", if you check this VS will do a lot of the work generating the wrapper

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: That question is different - it's a very specific question about a problem with a particular routine. This question is much more general

Answer (score 0):

You can make .NET assemblies expose COM, therefore you can access the classes by any technology/programming language which has COM support. See [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/nettocom.aspx) for example.