# Calling .Net Classes from Visual Basic 6

Tags: c#, .net, vb6

We have a .Net DLL.  We need to call this DLL from a VB Application.  What are the procedures we need to follow?

Comment: Duplicate of this question - although the answers here are much better, so maybe we should close the other question not this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131111/use-net-in-vb6-or-classical-asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last time I did this, it got so thorny (some irrelevant issues involving COM+, deployment, etc tripping us up) that I actually ditched the COM boundary, and re-wrote the interface as a POX web-service talking to a handler (ashx) in the .NET. I would give **serious** consideration to this approach... (unless you need to share windows handles, or similar)

---

If you *really* want a COM API, you need to generate a COM-callable wrapper; this is *largely* a case of:

- ensuring the necessary types / methods are public
- marking the assembly / types as `[ComVisible(true)]`
- using `tlbexe` to export the type library if you need
- using `regasm` to register the type in COM (either in the GAC or from a fixed location on a drive)

After that your VB6 *should* just see it as another COM package, but I *strongly* recommend that you limit this interface to the bare minimum; it isn't change-friendly, and the VB6-style interface forwarding (i.e. where you can get away with adding a method, without breaking binary compatibility) is not here.

Comment: Same steps we follow and finally we got the issue in VB application Compile error user defined type not definied

Comment: @subramani - does it list the reference in the VB6 IDE? And are you referencing the concrete type or the interface?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

- [C# Com](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb-interop/csCom.aspx)
- [COM Interop Exposed](http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/040721.htm)
- [C# Classes as COM Objects](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/05/c-classes-as-com-objects/)
- [Real Stories of .NET Interop: C#,
  VB.NET and VB6](http://www.vbrad.com/article.aspx?id=46)