# How to hash a UTF-8 string in Classic ASP

Tags: .net, asp-classic, utf-8, character-encoding, md5

I've been looking for a Classic ASP script that allows me to hash a string using the MD5 algorithm. I need to match this hashed string against the same string in an ASP.NET Page, hashed using .NET's MD5 hashing algorithms.

Even though I have found several scripts for Classic ASP that generate the hash, I haven't found one that generates the correct hash using non-English characters (like `ñ`, for example).

Do you know some Classic ASP script that works in this particular case?

**Note:**

I have tried these scripts:

http://userpages.umbc.edu/~mabzug1/cs/md5/md5.asp

http://forums.aspfree.com/code-bank-54/asp-classic-md5-hash-82164.html

**Examples:**

String:

```
muñeca
```

Correct MD5 Hash:

```
ea07bec1f37f4b56ebe368355d1c058f
```

Generated Hash:

```
298e60cb1179df15d5772726a3975132
```

Comment: You're question is essentially: How to encode a string with UTF-8 in ASP.net classic.

Comment: As a side-note, is there any reason for using MD5? It's old and broken in many scenarios. What are you using it for?

Comment: I hope you don't use it for password hashing or for security relevant data checking. Plain MD5 is too fast for passwords, and known collision attacks make it insecure for integrity checking.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I just need to match a simple string between ASP Classic and a .NET page in an intranet to make sure a hyperlink was generated and clicked by the same user. I didn't want to pass the string unencrypted and thought MD5 would be an easy solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of hashing any string is getting a byte array of the string's characters.  The byte array created depends on the **encoding** type used for the string. .Net strings are encoded in UTF-16. I don't recall vbscript's encoding type off the type of my head, but it's probably just ascii or at best UTF-8.

Therefore, to fix your problem, the first thing you need to do is get vbscript to give you a byte array that represents the UTF-16 characters in your string.  Then go look for an md5 hash function that expects a byte array directly, instead of a string type.

Unfortunately, even this may not be enough. It's possible that vbscript's lack of native UTF-16 could result in what is normally a *minor* loss of fidelity in the string input from the user, such that the string in your Classic ASP code is *no longer exactly the same characters* as the string in your ASP.Net code.  If this is the case, the only solution is to change your ASP.Net code to match the Classic ASP encoding, rather than vice versa. This may be the much easier solution anyway. For this to work, you will need to know *exactly* what character encoding your vbscript code is using. Again, I don't have that information in my head anymore, so you can google it as well as I.

Comment: The internal encoding of .net strings doesn't matter much, since you need to encode it anyways, since hash functions accept a `byte[]` not a `string`.

Answer (score 3):

The hash computation itself is not your problem. You're using UTF-8 in .net, and ANSI/Latin1 in asp classic.

A hash algorithm operates on a sequence of bytes, not on a string. Thus you first need to convert the string to a sequence of bytes first, a process called encoding. Common choices are ANSI(The locale dependent legacy encoding on windows), UTF-8 and UTF-16 LE.

First choose an encoding, and use that consistently on both platforms. I recommend UTF-8, which on .net is accessed via `Encoding.UTF.GetBytes()`. You'll need to search for UTF-8+asp classic to figure out how to use from there. Since UTF-8 encoding is a common problem, I'm sure you'll find something.

I suspect your asp classic code uses ANSI, but I strongly recommend not using it, since it only supports a small subset of possible characters, and is locale dependent.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using UTF-8 on both .Net and Classic ASP you should be able to borrow the .Net implementation.

Something like this;

```vb
<%
Dim asc, enc, bytes, instr, outstr, pos

instr = "muñeca"

Set asc = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
Set enc = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider")

bytes = asc.GetBytes_4(instr)
bytes = enc.ComputeHash_2((bytes))

outstr = ""

'Convert the Byte Array to a Hex string
For pos = 1 To LenB(bytes)
 outstr = outstr & LCase(Right("0" & Hex(AscB(MidB(bytes, pos, 1))), 2))
Next

Response.Write outstr
%>
```

Output:

```
ea07bec1f37f4b56ebe368355d1c058f
```

This is the only valid method I've found for Classic ASP because all other implementations assume ANSI encoding and you end up with an incorrect hash.

*Credit to: [Replicating PHP’s sha1() in VBScript](https://angrytechnician.wordpress.com/2011/02/11/replicating-phps-sha1-in-vbscript/) for helping me finally find a solution.*

Answer (score 1):

With this function you can hash the plain text into:
**SHA1, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, MD5, RIPEMD160**
If you need more you can find it in: [System.Security.Cryptography Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography(v=vs.110).aspx)

```vbs
Function Hash(HashType, PlainText)
    On Error Resume Next

    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Open
        .CharSet = "Windows-1252"
        .WriteText PlainText
        .Position = 0
        .CharSet = "UTF-8"
        PlainText = .ReadText
        .Close
    End With

    Set UTF8Encoding = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    Dim PlainTextToBytes, BytesToHashedBytes, HashedBytesToHex

    PlainTextToBytes = UTF8Encoding.GetBytes_4(PlainText)

    Select Case HashType
        Case "sha1": Set Cryptography = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed")
        Case "sha256": Set Cryptography = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed")
        Case "sha384": Set Cryptography = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA384Managed")
        Case "sha512": Set Cryptography = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed")
        Case "md5": Set Cryptography = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider")
        Case "ripemd160": Set Cryptography = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.RIPEMD160Managed")
    End Select

    Cryptography.Initialize()
    BytesToHashedBytes = Cryptography.ComputeHash_2((PlainTextToBytes))

    For x = 1 To LenB(BytesToHashedBytes)
        HashedBytesToHex = HashedBytesToHex & Right("0" & Hex(AscB(MidB(BytesToHashedBytes, x, 1))), 2)
    Next

    Hash = LCase(HashedBytesToHex)

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Response.Write(Err.Description)

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

These can be used as follows:

```vbs
Hash("sha512", "Hello World")
```

**Produces:**
2c74fd17edafd80e8447b0d46741ee243b7eb74dd2149a0ab1b9246fb30382f27e853d8585719e0e67cbda0daa8f51671064615d645ae27acb15bfb1447f459b

```vbs
Hash("sha256", "Hello World")
```

**Produces:**
a591a6d40bf420404a011733cfb7b190d62c65bf0bcda32b57b277d9ad9f146e

```vbs
Hash("md5", "muñeca")
```

**Produces:**
ea07bec1f37f4b56ebe368355d1c058f

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the .NET MD5 hashing code in a [COM-visible assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131111/use-net-in-vb6-or-classical-asp).  Then you can deploy and use the same exact MD5 hashing code on your ASP.NET and classic ASP sites.

Comment: His examples show that he has working md5 hashing in ASP.net classic, but that he's using ANSI instead of UTF8. So he'd need to import the encoding related code.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: my assumptions were 1) that the COM component would take a string as a parameter and convert the string to a byte array internally, using whatever encoding is desired, and 2) that VBScript and .NET would handle the conversion between VBScript string, BSTR (for COM interop), and .NET string without affecting any data due to different encodings.  To be fair, I couldn't find a good reference for the 2nd assumption, and I haven't tested it out.

Answer (score -3):

If you want exactly what .Net does , You can decompile **ComputeHash** method from **HashAlgorithm** class(also consider **MD5CryptoServiceProvider** class) from .Net assembly  **mscorlib.dll**  (from the path like this in your computer :C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll) 
and then convert the codes to ASP-Classic.
Some good (free)Decompilers are:

1- http://www.reflector.net/

2- http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx

Comment: 1) There are legal issues with decompiling and copying. 2) `MD5CryptoServiceProvider` is just a wrapper over unmanaged APIs 3) The MD5 part isn't the actual problem anyways.

Comment: 1) I'm not sure about it when you implement the code in different way. As I know Microsoft also released it for debugging cases too. You can just get some ideas ;-) 2) Are you sure? I didn't know it (but it is logical for performance issues too) 3) I had a different understanding. Anyway thanks for your clarification

Comment: You don't need to decompile it just use it's implementation via COM.