# can i run c# code from vba macro?

Tags: c#, vba

is it possible to include some kind of libraries inside of VBA that will enable me to use c# functions that i wrote?

Comment: please show me some code rather than giving me links

Comment: Did you click the links?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to expose managed code to COM using the `[ComVisible]` attribute.

For more information, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfww439.aspx).

**EDIT**: For example:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class MyClass {
    public int GetNumber(string name) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `ComVisible` attribute.
Here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233284/calling-net-methods-from-vb6-via-com-visible-dll)