# How to call python code from excel?

Tags: excel, python-2.7, vba

I have written a `python` code using `selenium` for automating files extraction from website and then I need to format these reports and append them and i am using macros for this.

Is there any way to call the `python` code from `excel` by integrating it with `VBA` or something like that?

Comment: [this may help you out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986234/can-i-run-c-sharp-code-from-vba-macro)

Comment: maybe using **OLE AUtomation** if the *Python* code is compiled to an executable or DLL or other ActiveX compliant doobri ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call python script on excel vba?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135551/how-to-call-python-script-on-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

you can write a code in python to populate excel [ Edit as well ] . There are libraries openpyexcel, xlrd etc more can be found [here](http://www.python-excel.org/)

It is easy for integration. Thanks