# How to run python function in Unix server using Excel VBA?

Tags: python, vba, unix, vbscript

I'd like to automate the below steps using Excel VBA/VB Script.
Here is the list of actions I do manually

Step1: login to winscp.

- Hostname: example.ash.pwj.com
- Port: 22
- UsrName: xxx Pwd: yyyy
- File Protocol: SFTP

transfer a file named 'testFile' from local machine to a Directory in Unix server using Winscp 
(the directory has a python script 'connector.py')

Step2: Open putty.

- Destination Host Name: example.ash.pwj.com
- Port: 22
- Connection Type: SSH
- Login using credentials.

Step3: call python script in the directory.
       `python connector.py argument1 argument2 argument3`

Example: `python connector.py testFile  example2.ash.pwj.com 123`

I have to handle WINSCP file transfer and calling python script in putty using Excel VBA/VBScript.

Here is my code:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

sh.Run "pscp -pw yyyy C:\Users\abc\testFile xxx@example.ash.pwj.com:/home/test/dir", 0, True
sh.Run "plink.exe -pw yyyy xxx@example.ash.pwj.com python /home/test/dir/connector.py testFile example2.ash.pwj.com 514", 0, True
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call python script on excel vba?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135551/how-to-call-python-script-on-excel-vba)

Comment: @will Not really a duplicate, since he wants to run a python script on a different host with a different operating system.

Comment: That can all be done from inside the python script being called though, can it not?

Comment: @will The Python script is called on the remote (Unix) host. We don't know if a Python interpreter is installed on the Windows machine, or if it's possible for the OP to install one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could shell out to [`pscp`](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp) and [`plink`](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink) from the [PuTTY suite](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html):

```vbs
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

sh.Run "pscp -pw yyyy c:\testFile xxx@example.com:/some/dir/", 0, True
sh.Run "plink -pw yyyy xxx@example.com python /some/dir/connector.py arg1 arg2 arg3", 0, True
```

Note that you need to add proper quoting if paths contain spaces.

If your destination path is just the destination directory without the filename: specify the path with a trailing filename. That way you'll get an error when the destination directory doesn't exist. Otherwise `pscp file user@example.com:/some/dir` might create a file `/some/dir` instead of `/some/dir/file` when there is no subdirectory `dir` in `/some`.

Also, you need to make sure that you pass the correct path to your Python script. When you copy the file to `/home/test/dir/` you should either change into that directory before calling the Python script, or specify the filename with its full path:

```
sh.Run "plink.exe -pw yyyy xxx@example.ash.pwj.com python /home/test/dir/connector.py /home/test/dir/testFile example2.ash.pwj.com 514", 0, True
```

Running the Python script from `/home/test/dir` doesn't automatically make that directory the current working directory.

Comment: I tried the above with appropriate paths. 
"The System cannot find file specified" error is thrown each time.!

Comment: @Prasanna Does any of the paths/filenames contain spaces? If so: did you quote the paths properly?

Comment: Hi Ansgar, paths/filenames does not have spaces. Note: arg2 is a filename present in /some/dir

Comment: sh.Run "pscp -pw yyyy C:\Users\abc\testFile xxx@example.ash.pwj.com:/home/test/dir", 0, True 


|| sh.Run "plink.exe -pw yyyy xxx@example.ash.pwj.com python /home/test/dir/connector.py testFile example2.ash.pwj.com 514", 0, True

Comment: @Prasanna Please don't post stuff like that in comments. Add it to your *question* instead. Is that code a single line in your script? If so: that won't work. `||` is a CMD operator. It's not valid in VBScript.

Comment: @Angsar I have updated my question with the code. I used || as a separator for the two lines of code. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.