# Embed python application as an OLE object in Excel

Tags: python, vba, excel, matplotlib, mayavi

Currently, I have an excel sheet that passes table data (x,y,z coordinates) to python script. The script plots the data either in matplotlib or mayavi and displays a separate interactive window where 3D plot can be manipulated.

Now I am wondering is it possible to embed my python code as an OLE object to excel. So that no separate window should be opened and plot could be rotated interactively inside the excel worksheet?

Comment: See [How to call python script on excel vba?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135551/how-to-call-python-script-on-excel-vba)

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  This is what I already do. My question is: Is it possible not to do this but embed the 3d plot directly in the worksheet.