# Call Gurobi Python from Excel VBA

Tags: python, excel, vba, gurobi

this is my first question on Stackoverflow, so don't be too hard on me, I'm a complete beginner.
I managed to write an optimization model in spyder with Gurobi as a solver, which gets its input from an excel workbook and returns the solution to Excel. Now, I simply want a Makro, that calls and executes that python script. I looked everywhere but all the presented solutions won't work. Highly appreciated if someone could help me out.

cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call python script on excel vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135551/how-to-call-python-script-on-excel-vba)

Comment: If you wrap the script in a class then it is callable from VBA using COM, http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/01/calling-python-class-using-vba-with-com.html