# Is it possible to run a python script from google sheets on a button press?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets

I have a script that reads from a google sheet and uses the information to create tickets using the Jira python api. In my situation it won't work to have the script be triggered at a certain time, the script has to be triggered through the sheet. Is there some way to detect a button press or a cell change which runs my local python file?

Comment: May we see what did you do so far?

Comment: I would suggest VBA to program a macro that can call the python script on shell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call python script on excel vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135551/how-to-call-python-script-on-excel-vba)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. 
there is a tool set call 'gspread', which can read from python data from your Google sheets.
What I did is a script in the spread sheet, what filled a cell with "Start + time". You can trigger script with this with a button.

Now the python program read this cell every minute. If the cell contains the start trigger, if fires the python script.

Not the nicest solution, but it works for a few years now.