# Is there a way to make python and excel interact?

Tags: python, excel

I have a dropdown option on excel. I want that when the user inputs something on that dropdown, my python script automatically starts running and enters the output into the excel file.

I know how to make python read and write into excel files and that part of the code works fine. However, I have difficulty automating the process.

Is there a way for python to automatically start running?

Comment: There: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: I think this link should be useful for what you're trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135551/how-to-call-python-script-on-excel-vba

Comment: Also this: https://www.xlwings.org/