# Is there a way to make an excel macro run a python program and insert the output into the same spreadsheet?

Tags: python, excel

Given a spreadsheet with a column of string values, what is the best way using an excel macro (or additional python script) to use the given string as input and insert the output of a python script into the next column.

(My first time using both StackOverflow and excel Macro programming, please forgive me here!)

Comment: to read excel file data use openpyxl or xlrd package. to embed output file to particular cell use win32com package.

Comment: Check out the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18135876/6908282