# How to assign a Python script to a button in Outlook?

Tags: python, vba, outlook

I have the below Python code:

```
    import win32com.client as client
outlook = client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
namespace = outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI')

account = namespace.Folders['email account']

inbox = account.Folders['Inbox']


print(inbox.Name)
print(inbox.Parent.Name)
print(inbox.Items.Count)

HMEmails = [message for message in inbox.Items if message.SenderEmailAddress.startswith('ics.notifier')]

for message in HMEmails:
    print(message)


folder = inbox.Folders('ICS Reports')

for message in HMEmails:
    message.Move(folder)
```

When run via the command prompt, this code returns the number of email items in the specified folder, the names of them, and also moves them to a separate folder if they meet the criteria.

I understand that I must use Visual Basic for Applications to use the code within the Outlook application, but what would the VBA code for that look like? And is there a way to then assign the above script function to a button within Outlook so that the function is applied after clicking?

EDIT:
It seems the VBA code to run the Python script is rather simple. Below is the code that I thought should work:

```vb
'Initialise function
Sub RunPythonScript()
    
    'Provision of file path locations to Python Exe and script
    PythonExe = "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe"
    PythonScript = """C:\Users\user\OneDrive - laptop\Documents\A&I\Python\offAutomation.py"""
    
    'Invoke the Python script
    Shell (PythonExe & PythonScript)
    
End Sub
```

When I click "Run" I get an error

> "file not found" error.

Both file locations are valid since I am able to access both by pasting them into my search bar.

Comment: Plenty of examples to be had here on SO. 
 Eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135551/how-to-call-python-script-on-excel-vba  Also plenty of pointers if you Google "vba run python script" so maybe start there and post back if you run into a specific problem calling your script.

Comment: Cheers Tim, I'll give them a look through and report back

Comment: I've entered in an edit, I don't suppose you know why it says "file not found" when they're definitely valid locations do you? TIA

Comment: Maybe try adding a space between the two paths, or for the second one try a non-OneDrive path.

Comment: Thank you Tim, works fine now. To solve, I used the following: Shell (PythonExe & " " & PythonScript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to Tim Williams for the help on this. In order to run an external Python script from Outlook using `VBA` see the following example:

```
'Initialise function
Sub RunPythonScript()

'Provision of file path locations to Python Exe and script
PythonExe = "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe"
PythonScript = """C:\Users\user\OneDrive - laptop\Documents\A&I\Python\offAutomation.py"""

'Invoke the Python script
Shell (PythonExe & " " & PythonScript)

End Sub
```

Please note, the triple quotation marks for the `PythonScript` variable are necessary since there are spaces present within the file path.

1. The `Sub` function has been defined at the start
2. In my case, two variables have been assigned file paths for Python.exe and my Python script
3. The `Shell` function at the end runs the variables file paths, but they needed to be split by a space next to the ampersand symbol - that is why it didn't run originally.
4. `End Sub` marks the end of the VBA code.