# Create a button to run a .exe file in Outlook and MS teams

Tags: outlook, exe, microsoft-teams, ribbonx

I would like to add a button on outlook and/or MS teams to run a .exe program that I developed with python.
I tried to look online but I didn't find anything.
Can someone knows how to do it or if it is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to assign a Python script to a button in Outlook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64649817/how-to-assign-a-python-script-to-a-button-in-outlook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a VBA macro in Outlook which runs an external executable. And then assign it to the QAT button. See [Assign a macro to a button](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/assign-a-macro-to-a-button-728c83ec-61d0-40bd-b6ba-927f84eb5d2c#:%7E:text=Add%20a%20macro%20button%20to,on%20the%20Quick%20Access%20Toolbar.) for more information.