# Run a python code (Anaconda3) using a VBA button in the Excel input workbook

Tags: python, excel, vba, anaconda

I wrote a Python code that performs some calculations using as input data in an excel workbook.
My goal is to add a button inside the input excel workbook that automatically run the python script.
I have already added the button to which I've associated the following macro:

'''

```
Sub RunPythonScript()

    Dim objShel As Object
    Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String
    
    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    
    PythonExe = "*path to python.exe*"
    
    PythonScript = """*path to the code*"""
    
    objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript

End Sub
```

'''

The macro isn't working and returns the error *Method 'Run' of object IWshShell3 failed*!
I don't know if the issue is due to the fact that I have the input excel workbook for the python code open (usually should be closed to make the code works).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call python script on excel vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135551/how-to-call-python-script-on-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try put that run python command into a bat file then run that bat file

Comment: I was able to overcome the error message but however now when I run the VBA code nothing happens!